# A proof with a lim sup ratio test

Tags: real-analysis

Let us recall the ratio test:

If $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|{b_{n+1} \over b_n}\right |  < 1$ then $\sum b_n$ converges.

Now let $\sum a_n x^n$ be a power series and let $L = \limsup_{n \to \infty}\left | {a_{n+1} \over a_n} \right | $ and assume $L \neq 0$ and $x \in (-{1 \over L}, {1 \over L})$. My goal is to show that then $\sum a_n x^n$ converges.

Please could somebody tell me if my thoughts are correct?

Because $\lim \le \limsup$ one can apply the ratio test as follows:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\left | {a_{n+1} x^{n+1}\over a_n x^n} \right | \le \limsup_{n \to \infty}\left | {a_{n+1} x^{n+1} \over a_n x^n} \right | = \limsup_{n \to \infty}\left | {a_{n+1}  \over a_n } \right | |x|= L |x|< 1$$

therefore $\sum a_n x^n$ converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you write $\lim$, you must prove that it exists. If $a$ alternates between $1$ and $2$, the very first limit you write does not exist, so your proof cannot be correct.