# Two questions about this solution /proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Consider the following theorem:

If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n $ converges for all $x \in (-R,R)$ then the differentiated series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n a_n x^{n-1}$ converges for all $x \in (-R,R)$.

And now consider the following proof:

[image]

I am not sure this is correct. My doubts are the following:

(1) Is it correct to write $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty |n a_n x^{n-1}| = \dots$$

before proving it converges?

(2) By assumption $\sum_n a_n x^n$ only converges but not necessarily absolutely. Why is it clear that $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n t^n|$$ is finite?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. $\sum x_n = \sum y_n$ here means that the sequences of terms of each are the same. In particular, it is then correct that if the second sum converges, so does the first. Similarly, $\sum x_n \leq \sum y_n$ here means that the $n$'th term of the left hand sum is smaller than the $n$'th term of the right-hand sum.
2. This is how convergence works for power series. Inside the interval of convergence, you converge *absolutely*; outside it, nothing converges at all; and on the boundary, it depends. Here by assumption $t<R$, so we're good.

Comment: Thank you I understand 2. But not 1.... I'm sorry. I tried to do something similar [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800391/a-proof-with-a-lim-sup-ratio-test) but I was told I can't write the limit before I show it exists. Here in the answer it seems that $$ \sum_n |n a_n x^{n-1}|$$ is a limit but it is not shown yet to exists. Please could you say something more about 1?

Comment: @blue "You can't write $\lim$ before proving it exists" is just a way of saying "It's an abuse of notation". Like all abuses of notation, they're fine as long as you're clear about what you *really* mean. In the case of the proof you linked to, all you show is that *if the limit exists*, then $\lim<\limsup$. In the present case, however, if you interpret the abuse of notation like I said, you'll see that the proof is correct.